# Change WooCommerce New order admin FROM email address to that of customer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need WooCommerce to send specific emails from the customer's email address rather than the admin email address.

**Background:**

I'm setting up a paid support service which uses WooCommerce for payments and bbPress as a ticketing system.

A user orders a service product through WooCommerce and a new WooCommerce order is created. The order needs to then populate a ticketing system and my workaround is to have the 'New order' email sent to an email inbox and then pulled in by the ticketing system. Obviously this is not perfect and introduces a point of failure but it's fine for now.

The problem is that the new order email is sent from the WooCommerce admin email address, so the new ticket is associated with that account rather than the account of the user who created the order.

So I need the email from address to be the address of the user that submitted the order.

Is this possible with a hook?

in `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php` we have the following:

```
public function send( $to, $subject, $message, $headers = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n", $attachments = '' ) {
    // Send.
    $email = new WC_Email();
    return $email->send( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
}
```

This doesn't include the sender, and as it's buried in a class, could it be overridden anyway?

Greatful for any pointers.

(PS I do appreciate there are issues with this approach, including emails being flagged as spam, but initially this will be manageable until I get a more robust system in place)

(PPS I'm aware there is an almost identical question but the links aren't working and relates to a very out of date WooCommerce)

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible to send the email from your customer email address. You can only set the customer email to `Reply-To` in WP_Mail header.
In my experience, you should send another email to your sepcific email inbox, and skip the email sent by WooCommerce by default. Use this hook:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing', 'order_created_send_email');

function order_created_send_email($order_id, $order) {
    $customer_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    /* Code to send email with Reply-To: customer email */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've decided to go another route and am using the woocommerce_thankyou hook to duplicate the order as a bbPress topic. Seems like a safer approach than my original workaround.